# How to assign Each Row a Unique ID and have it reset every time it is run

Tags: mariadb, navicat

I have a view and i want to assign each row a unique number and i want the increment of numbers to always start at 1 each time it is run and i would like the Numbering to reset itself to 1 every time the CustomerID changes.

Views do not support subquerying of variables in MariaDb, so i am trying to create a function that the view would then reference.

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION `func_inc_var_session`() RETURNS int
    NO SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
     begin
      SET @var := @var + 1;
       return @var;
     end
     //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Perhaps this is something that could be done with either [`RANK`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/rank/) or [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/) window functions?

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk